# Align flex nav items at the bottom of a containing div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to align 3 tabbed items (using ul flexbox items) **on top** of an image at the bottom using a containing div, but for the life of me, I can't get them all to stay within the containing div.

If I use `position:absolute; bottom:0;` It makes everything worse, so I am a bit stuck how to fix it! I also tried `margin-top:auto` on the `<li>` , and that didn't help either.

Here is the JSFiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/929n6tq3/30/) or code directly:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400">
  <ul class=flextabs>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  border:solid;
}

ul.flextabs {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display:flex;
}
li {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    background:red;
    padding:5px;
}
a:hover{background:orange;}
```

This is the current result:

[image: current]

vs What I would like to achieve (above image edited)

[image: trying to get]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `position: absolute;` on the `ul` to place it at the bottom of the container, and apply `flex` to it - not to the container or to the `li`s. And I also changed and added some other details:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

ul.flextabs {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400">
  <ul class=flextabs>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```